# Cross Browser Jquery Regular Expression for Name

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to allow a user to enter alphabets only. But the buttons `Home`, `End`, `Backspace`, `Delete` and `Arrow keys` should work within the textbox.

I have written following jQuery code to achieve this.

The regular expression `^[a-zA-Z]*$` works fine in Chrome but not with Mozilla FireFox

```js
$('#Firstname').bind('keypress', function (e) {
 var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]*$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Firstname" type="text"/>
```

Thank You

Comment: I'm on a Mac Book Air at the moment, and I will confirm that it does appear to work with Safari.

Comment: It works in Internet Explorer but not Firefox? Never thought I'd see the day

Comment: I dont think this problem causes the regex, but the calling and function wrapped around it. Regex sticks to a defined ruleset

Comment: The keypress event would not catch if a person pastes a value to the field with the mouse.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you confirm my answer works in Safari?

Comment: @ctwheels It works on Safari and Chrome on my Mac Book Air.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks I'll add a notes section for compatibility

Comment: @Felix
You may be right.But it works in Chrome and not in Mozilla Firefox. I didn't test in Safari.

Comment: @Taplar
Yes, we can validate test on 'focusout' event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Brief

According to Mozilla's documentation, both [`KeyboardEvent.charCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode) and [`KeyboardEvent.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) are deprecated (`charCode` is also considered *Non-standard*).

#### charCode

The documentation for `KeyboardEvent.charCode` contains the following messages

[image: Non-standard message]
[image: Deprecated message]
[image: Alternative message]

#### which

The documentation for `KeyboardEvent.which` contains the following message

[image: Deprecated message]

---

### Code

```js
$('#Firstname').bind('keypress', function (e) {
 var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]*$");
    if (regex.test(e.key)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Firstname" type="text"/>
```

---

### Compatibility

I tested my answer in the following browsers; each of which works:

- Chrome: 63.0.3239.84 (as well as Chrome for OSX - thanks to [@TimBiegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen))
- Firefox: 58.0b11
- Edge: 41.16299.15.0
- Internet Explorer: 11.125.16299.0
- Safari (thanks to [@TimBiegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen))

Also, see Mozilla's documentation for [`KeyboardEvent.key` browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Thank you so much.Let me check.

Comment: Thank you.
This works fine for Chrome  63.0.3239.108. But it Accepting digits and special characters on lower version of chrome browser (i.e 31.0.1650.59).Do you have any Idea, what I need to do?